# Scrapy: Using CSS Selectors to exclude a node/tag

Tags: python, scrapy

In the documentation and SO articles, there are only references on how to exclude CSS classes using this nomenclature:

```
response.css("div[id='content']:not([class*='infobox'])")
```

What I want to achieve however is to exclude a node, or even, multiple nodes, such as `<span>` and `<div>` elements which are inside an `<li>` element.

Let me give you an example. Let's say I am scraping this HTML:

```
<li class="classA">
  <div class="classB">
    ..
  </div>

  <span class="classC">Whatever</span>

  This is the string I want to scrape
</li>
```

,and I am only interested in scraping the text "This is the string I want to scrape", thus I want to skip both `<div>` and `<span>` nodes. I tried to use the following, inside the scrapy shell, to no avail:

```
response.css(".classA:not(span|div)::text").extract()
```

,but I am still getting the excluded nodes.

Comment: As Ivan pointed out in the answer you can avoid not syntax completely by selecting direct child (no space before ::text) instead of any descendant  (child, grandchild)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's very easy:

### 1. Using css selector

```
response.css('li.classA::text').extract_first()
```

### 2. Using xpath selector

```
response.xpath('//li[@class = "classA"]/text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
response.css('li::text').extract_first()
```